Given a rectangular box $ABCD.A'B'C'D'$, initially, a bug starts at vertex $A$.
Given a rectangular box $ABCD.A'B'C'D'$, initially, a bug starts at vertex $A$. In one move, the bug can crawl along the edge of the rectangular box to an adjacent vertex. Calculate the number of ways the bug can reach vertex $C ′$ after $n$ moves.
After many attempts using code, I found the recurrence relation $f(n)=10f(n−2)−9f(n−4)$ with initial conditions $f(3)=6$ and $f(5)=60$. However, I am unsure how to prove this mathematically, so I am seeking assistance with this proof. Hope everyone can help me with this problem thanks.
